# Slide out menu control not working Xcode 7 / Swift 2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

I have made a sideBar menu table that when you slide from left to right, the table appears. I have made cells and want to go to a different view controller when I click on them, but my current code it not doing that. When I click, they just stay highlighted and don't go anywhere. No code errors.

```
var sideBar: SideBar = SideBar()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sideBar = SideBar(sourceView: self.view, menuItems: ["Home", "Calendar", "Announcements", "Recordings", "Social Media", "Photos"])
    sideBar.delegate = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(index: Int) {
    var socialVC : UIViewController
    if index == 0 {
            // handle twitter
            socialVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PhotosViewController") as! PhotosViewController
        } else if index == 1 {
            // handle facebook
            socialVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CalendarViewController") as! CalendarViewController
        } else {
            // handle remind
            socialVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AnnouncementsViewController") as! AnnouncementsViewController
        }
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(socialVC, animated: true)
    }
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

  }
}
```